# Java I/O to pipe

Tags: java, io, pipe

For some reason this code only works when I close the output stream.  How can I get it to work without having to close it?

I want to keep it open so I could keep sending data to the process without restarting it.

```
ProcessBuilder pbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(procCmds);
            pbuilder.directory(new File(workingDir));
            Process p = pbuilder.start();

    BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    String str = "hello world heard from java\n";
    outputStream.write(str, 0, str.length());
    outputStream.flush();
    System.out.println("wrote " + str);
    BufferedReader errorStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while((line=errorStream.readLine())!=null)
        System.out.println(line);
    while((line=inputStream.readLine())!=null)
        System.out.println(line);

    //p.waitFor();
    outputStream.close();
    errorStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
```

Comment: Yes I did.  It's in the code there.  outputStream.flush().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either merge the error and inputs streams or else read one of them in a separate thread. At present you are attempting to read the error stream to EOS, which only happens when the process exits, so you never get to read the input stream at all. You won't get EOS on the input stream either until the process exits, so reading it to EOS doesn't really make sense either if you have further output to provide. Probably you should read both streams in separate threads.

Comment: Thanks.  Merging the streams is the best thing to do here.  I wasn't aware that the error stream only returns EOS when it exits.  To confirm, i removed the error-stream read code and it worked.

Comment: @jortz When else could it possibly return EOS? The process can write to stderr any time it likes so it certainly can't sensibly close it any sooner.

Comment: I'm not confused about the logic behind the mechanism, I just didn't account for it.  In fact, to my point, it also works if i add errorStream.ready() in the while loop condition and wrap the whole thing in a while loop.  The problem is that I block UNTIL the EOS is emitted.  I just need to remove that block and i'm good to go.  The same can be said for reading the stdout of the process via the inputstream.

Comment: @jortiz81 It doesn't work if you test ready(), it just changes the behaviour to another wrong behaviour, and you're *supposed* to read to EOS, otherwise the process may block and never exit. That's why you have to either merge the streams or read one of them in a separate thread, as I told you above. I can never understand why people ask for advice and then do something different from the answer they are given.

Comment: Wrong.  It actually does work.  I don't understand how you can be so confident if you didn't test the code yourself.  I changed the code to do the ready() test and it worked and hasn't broken in any of our tests for the last 6 weeks.

Also, the incoming stream is continuous, so testing for EOS is meaningless.